# Array intersect not displaying right answers

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with PHP and i have filled an array of 2000 words from database. Now i am using this array to compare with user entered text in textarea to find common words. But the problem is after comparison only 2 3 words are matched, even though the words entered by the user are present in the 2000 words array.

E.g. user entered: “hello! today is sunday and a warm day.”
My filled array contains: `[hello,today,sunday,warm]`.
It should display these 4 words but its only displaying "hello" and "warm".

Here is the code:

```
$positive = array();

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM positive";
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $sql1);

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    $positive[] = $row1['pword'];
}
$text = $_POST['text'];
$array = explode( ' ', $text );
$result_parray = array_intersect($positive, $array);
print_r($result_parray);
```

Please can anyone tell me why the other words are not displayed?
I am really confused... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are user input and database values both mixed case?

Comment: they both are in lowercase

Comment: from your example `Hello!` should also have not been part of the result as your array (Hello,Today,Sunday,Warm) doesn't have `Hello!`

Comment: And 'Hello' is not lowercase.

Comment: Use print_r for both array $positive, $array u will get the idea

Comment: okay thanks it helped for the solution

Comment: @Ahmadßutt, add your solution and accept it. It may help others in understanding a similar problem

Comment: @codeHeart everything is right about the code but now i have noticed that there is some problem with database

Comment: i just updated some rows in the table and they are displayed. Actually i entered these 2000 words through a file in database maybe thats causing problem

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue due to cases of the word being different

Try using

```
$result_parray = array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', $positive), array_map('strtolower', $array));
```

But this will not retain the original case of your words

Comment: i tired this but still same problem.

Comment: the words in array and user entered array are already in lowercase. its really confusing for me

Comment: @Ahmadßutt Please show us the output of: `var_dump($positive);` and `var_dump($array);` with your example data from the question.

Comment: @Rizier123 i got the problem, it's in database i'll solve that first if any issues i'll tell

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
    $result_parray = array_uintersect($positive, $array, "strcasecmp");
```

Comment: same problem, user input and array words are in lowercase